# brew install cmake unable to find formula

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I am trying to install cmake on a new machine running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 using homebrew:

`brew install cmake`

results in

`Error: No available formula with the name "cmake" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Can I not install cmake using homebrew?

Update:  I tested this on a new machine, and it just installed without issue.  I'm not sure what's going on with the current machine, but if it's index issue as indicated below, how do I go about fixing it?  I've already run `brew update`.

Comment: There seems to be right now some problem with the Homebrew index right now.

Comment: It's been like this for about a week...

Answer (score 1):

I were facing the same issue while installing Go, ran
`brew doctor`

fixed all the warnings as the hint was given by brew doctor command
then again gave installation command
`brew update && brew install golang`

it worked, you can do the same for your package

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out what was wrong, but I was able to fix the problem by completely uninstalling homebrew

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

and then reinstalling it

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!

```
rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
brew tap homebrew/core
```